# How many neurons are required in convolution layer of CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

How many neurons are required  in convolution layer to process  image of size 32 * 32 with
32 filters and kernel size 3 * 3. I know input neurons will be 32*32 i.e 1024 but how to calculate neurons required in hidden convolution layer

Comment: The number of neurons in a layer is not something that is calculable.

Answer (score 0):

A convolutional layer consists of filters, I don't think they are conventionally called neurons. So I guess the answer to your question is 32. Also note that the kernel size and the image size do not matter. The kernel size affects the number of parameters but (obviously) not the number of filters.

That is the point of convolutional layer - it does not matter what is the size of the input, the number of parameters is fixed.

Comment: I encounter terminology where feature from feature map(output of conv layer) was marked as neuron. It makes some sense because one feature at feature map is computed as kernel weights x input and then nonlinearity is aplied which is similar to how   "normal" artificial neuron operates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fix method or terminology to define the number of hidden units in a network (you reference it as neuron), but what is advised is that keep the number of hidden units less than the number of features.

Example : your input feature has size 256 (16 by 16 image) than the number of hidden unit should be kept under 256 for a good fit and preventing overfitting !
More neurons will overfit the data introducing a high variance(test set error greater than training error)